# Upgrading dualboot to Win 8.1

Tags: 13.10, windows-8, uefi

I have my Ideapad Y400 dualbooting Ubuntu 13.10 and Win8, both in EFI.  I don't honestly know how I managed it.  Is there any chance that updating Win8 to Win8.1 via the Microsoft Store would break my dual installation?

Answer (score 1):

Such an upgrade shouldn't damage the Linux installation (but I don't guarantee that), but it will almost certainly set the Windows boot loader as the default. This will necessitate restoring GRUB (or whatever you're using as a boot manager) as the default boot program. You can do this in Windows via the `bcfg` command, in Linux with the `efibootmgr` utility, or in various other ways.